# Ffmpeg bluray option

Tags: video, ffmpeg, blu-ray, documentation

let's take for example I got this https://nyaa.si/view/1235388
According to FFmpeg usage to take Bluray as input we can use

```
ffmpeg -i bluray:"path/to/bluray/" -map 0 -c copy -c:a flac remuxed-bluray.mkv
```

and for this file, it will be something like

```
ffmpeg -i bluray:"[BDMV] Oshi ga Budoukan Itte Kuretara Shinu - Vol.01" -map 0 -c copy -c:a flac remuxed-bluray.mkv
```

The above gives only one output but as you can see from the file structure its not only one episode but consists of 6 episode and rest BD menus.

So what should I use to get all the 6 episodes and bd menus separately?

***Please Don' t give me that just do the following***

```
ffmpeg -i "[BDMV] Oshi ga Budoukan Itte Kuretara Shinu - Vol.01/BDMV/stream/00000.m2ts" -map 0 -c copy -c:a flac remuxed-bluray.mkv
```

***as input and encode it. Since I know this, but due to poor documentation very less is provided about Blurays encode***